# Extracing a sublist from a list and copying it into a new list

Tags: r, list

i want to store a new element inside a list, which is its length. It works outside of a for-loop, but not if its inside one.
example:

for element 2 of the list:

```
file_dis[[2]]$length <- length(file_dis[[2]]$X)
```

stores the length of the column (225) 225 times as a new column.

However this for loop does not produce new columns.

```
for (dr in length(file_dis)) { #Store amount for each file
  file_dis[[dr]]$length <- length(file_dis[[dr]]$X)
}
```

I don't know how to continue.

I have previously tried storing the length as one value (not 225 times) in a seperate list, as a more elegant solution. But that did not work either.

```
for (dr in length(file_dis)) { #Store amount for each file
  length_dis[[dr]] <- length(file_dis[[dr]]$X) 
}
```

every [[dr]] list except the last one is empty. My script seems to always overwrite the old list instead of appending new data.

Comment: What does the data inside your list look like? Are they dataframes? Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) out so that we can better answer your question.

Comment: Try using `for (dr in seq_along(1:length(file_dis)))`

Comment: I believe @Phil means`for (dr in seq_along(file_dis)`. This is equivalent to `for (dr in 1:length(file_dis)`. This will probably solve your issue but is not really the best way to go about transforming your data. Take a look at `?apply` or `?purrr::map`

Comment: Correct, I haven't fully woken up yet.

Comment: Thank you both for the input, i will try out your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not sure if I understand what you are trying to do, providing context, a reproducible example or both is great, still, I'll try to answer. I might fail though.

given a nested list:

```
x <- list(A = list(A1 = 1, A2 = 2, A3 = 3), B = list(B1 = 1, B2 = 2, B3 = 3))
```

you can add a new element to part of the sublist with either:

```
x$A$new <- "4"
x[["A"]][["new"]] <- "4"
```

and so, you might add that new element to all sublists with a simple for loop

```
for (i in 1:length(x)){
    name <- names(x[i])
    x[[name]][["new"]] <- 4
}
```

hope it either solves or at least helps you out.
Finally also note i'm using `1:` in `1:lenght(x)`
you can easily test the difference, the idea is that without it i'll only be looping once by the last element

Comment: Thank you very much. I was simply missing the `1:` in the for loop counter and its now working.